# TeXLive2013: mdugm.sty not found

Tags: fonts

Suddenly my TeXLive installation with non-free fonts produces an error about the package `mdugm.sty`. Here is my source file:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

\title{Tentative schedule}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\textbf{Hour} & \textbf{Wednesday} & \textbf{Thursday}  \\ \hline 
9:30 & Stuart & Valdinoci  \\ \hline
10:30 & Stuart & Valdinoci   \\ \hline
11:20 & Coffee break & Coffee break  \\ \hline
11:45 & Tilli & Lewin  \\ \hline
12:35 & Lunch & Lunch  \\ \hline
15:00 & Smets & Cingolani \\ \hline
16:00 & S\'er\'e &  Krieger \\ \hline
16:50 & Coffee break & Coffee break  \\ \hline
17:20 & Teta & Pisante  \\ \hline
18:10 &  \null & Schlein  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I compiled this source a few days ago without any warning, so I suspect that some packages were broken in an update. How can I use URW Garamond fonts as before?

**Edit:** the package "mathdesign" was updated on Sept. 2 from version 24173 to version 31552. This is clearly the reason of my problem, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Revert to an older version of mathdesign, or wait a bit: There was a discussion about it on the texlive list and it looks as if the fonts will be included again.

Comment: Thanks, now I've found the discussion in the mailing list archives. Well, I'll wait a few days.

Comment: These changes broke one of my large documents. @UlrikeFischer: where can I find the version of mathdesign from Tex Live 2012? Is there a way to cleanly and quickly extract packages from an existing Tex Live install?

Comment: TL has a backup system. So why don't you simply revert with the texlive manager? http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#restore---backupdir-dir---all-pkg-rev-

Comment: Actually, after some tragic attempt, I managed to install the mathdesign fonts manually, as described in the README file of the package. It is definitely easier than it is generally considered, but I still think that we should wait for a clean package from the maintainer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This assumes there is a backup in the first place. This problem arose between complete Tex Live releases: it worked in 2012, does not work in 2013. A full upgrade was not possible this year https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html, so 'tlmgr --restore' won't help me here.

Comment: @Siminore We may be waiting a while. Which manual installation instructions did you follow?

Comment: @StephenBosch http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign and http://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html

I work on a Mac, and this may slightly change the steps that you'd perform on a Linux box. However, it worked for me. In particular, I did not edit `updmap.cfg` as suggested by the maintainer; I used the `sudo -H updmap-sys` to enable each map.

Another solution is to reinstall TL2013 and exclude mathdesign from the updates... I had to do this after breaking the tree with my stupid experiments.

Comment: So this problem resulted from an update and is not present in the Tex Live 2013 base distribution?

Comment: No, everything worked until Sep. 1 or 2 (it depends on your CTAN mirror).

Comment: I downloaded the Tex Live 2013 ISO image and installed from that. I skipped the update. I had to update a few packages to address some other errors, but in the end this approach worked for me.

Comment: Now you can even type `tlmgr update --exclude mathdesign --all` to update everything but mathdesign. It works for me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved with a software update